# XML and Java... Confused about Values versus Index?

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to understand how to read out XML files using Java. I would like to have one XML tag, lets call it enable, pass a true to a method and another XML tag that provides a number to another method. I would like to pass the true by having the line  in my XML file and pass the number as valueofnumber. I am reading out the XML file using a series of if statements testing for certain strings in an XML file:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
    {
    if (localName.equals("enabled")){
        currentConfig.setenabled(true);
    }
    else if (localName.equals("number")){
        currentConfig.setnumber(Double.parseDouble(attributes.getValue("number")))
    }
}
```

I am getting confused as to how extract the value of number from the XML file. Currently I am just getting an error that nothing is present when I try getIndex() as well.

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Are you confusing the element name (localName) with an attribute value?  Show us the XML you're trying to read.

Comment: I don't see any call to `getIndex`.  I don't see where `attributes` or `localName` are declared / initialized.  Please show us ALL of the relevant code.

Comment: Can you paste in some sample XML?

Comment: It looks like he's doing raw SAX parsing and this is an implementation of [DefaultHandler.startElement()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#startElement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes%29).

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<runConfig>
    <elementConfigList hub="1001">element-test</elementConfigList>
    <triggerConfig>TestTrigger</triggerConfig>
    <runComponent name="Trigger"/>
    </enabled>
    <number>25</number>
</runConfig>`
Some sample XML

Comment: @madtowneast: not well-formed XML. You have no open tag for `</enabled>`

Comment: You might find StAX parsers more easy to work with

Answer (score 1):

The [getValue() method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html#getValue%28java.lang.String%29) you're calling takes a qualified name, meaning XML namespace + local name in the format :. Your XML document probably uses a namespace, which you'd have to supply. If there's no namespace, you might need to use the [other getValue() method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html#getValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and pass `null` for the namespace. It all depends a lot on what parser you're using and how it's configured. You'd be better advised to move to a higher-level parsing library that takes care of these nuances for you:

- [StAX](http://stax.codehaus.org/Home) isn't much higher level than SAX, but it still has a friendlier and generally more intuitive interface.
- [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/), being a DOM parser, will be slightly less efficient, but it makes parsing XML incredibly easy.
- [Commons Digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/) is kind of a rules-based XML parsing engine. You establish rules for what you want to happen when this or that element or attribute is encountered, and then run the digester. Method calls are one of the rules you can set, as is creation and population of a POJO.
- [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) or [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) will completely remove the guesswork and bind the XML straight to POJOs with minimal configuration. Then you don't even have to deal with XML and can work with normal objects instead.

**Edit:** (Based on the XML sample) Your "number" isn't an attribute. It's a nested element. That's why you're having trouble getting it from the Attributes object. My other advice on other libraries still stands.